# When EM waves travel through a material with refraction index n, is the formula $\lambda = \frac{c}{n \cdot f}$ correct?

Tags: waves

When EM waves travel through a material with refraction index n, ist the formula $\lambda = \frac{c}{n \cdot f}$ correct? c is the speed of light in vacuum and f the frequency of the wave. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

n is called the [refractive index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refractive_index) and can be defined as follow :
$$
n = \frac{c}{v}
$$
With $v$ being the wave's [phase velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_velocity).

The "true" relation would be :
$$
\lambda = \frac{v}{f}
$$
Which according the definition of $n$ gives
$$
\lambda = \frac{c}{nf}
$$

$n$ is also defined by:
$$
n = \sqrt{\epsilon_r} = \sqrt{\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon_0}}
$$
With $\epsilon_0$, $\epsilon$ and $\epsilon_r$ being respectively the vacuum's [dielectric permittivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity), the material's dielectric permittivity, and the material's relative permittivity.